# How to get TargetDataLine from Speakers?

Tags: java, audio, audio-recording, javasound

How do you get the TargetDataLine from the Speakers? I know how to do it for Microphones, but I can't figure it out for speakers. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TargetDataLine` is for reading data which does not make sense for speakers.

`SourceDataLine` is used to send data to speakers. You can get this from `AudioSystem.getLine()` or a `Mixer`.

You need `DataLine.Info` which is something like this:

```
   DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
```

`audioFormat` is an AudioFormat instance - you can get this from an `AudioInputStream` instance `getFormat()` call or just construct a new instance of AudioFormat.

Comment: K, SourceDataLine is what I meant then. :D It says I need to specify Info though so what Info do I specify for Speakers?

Comment: Updated answer with info about the info.

Comment: [Java Sound Resources](http://www.jsresources.org/) has useful stuff about Java audio.